# carregar xml em gridview

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

Em meu projeto, preciso selecionar um arquivo XML de alguma pasta do HD e depois ler seu conteudo e mostrar em uma gridview.

Neste momento, eu consigo [abrir a janela para selecionar o arquivo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx), mas não consigo ler esse arquivo e iterar sobre ele e mostrar os dados do XML em um gridview...

Como posso fazer ?

Meus códigos:

```
 Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialogXML = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialogXML.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialogXML.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialogXML.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialogXML.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialogXML.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialogXML.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        string caminhoArquivo = openFileDialogXML.ToString();

                        XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
                        documento.Load(caminhoArquivo);
                        string docLoaded = documento.ToString(); 
                        // Insert code to read the stream here.

                        //classe que representa um xml, e faz o parse da string para o arquivo
                        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(docLoaded);

                        //cria a representação de uma tabela
                        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));
                        tabela.Columns.Add("tabela", typeof(string));

                        ////cria as linhas da tabela
                        DataRow registro;

                        ////itera sobre a tag do xml para pegar todos os dados 
                        foreach (var elmCertidao in doc.Root.Elements("tag"))
                        {
                      
                            //recebe os registros do xml e representa em linhas
                            registro = tabela.NewRow();

                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                            registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));

                        //    //objeto com todas as colunas
                            tabela.Rows.Add(registro);
                        }

                        ////monta o grid com as informações presentes no objeto
                        dgDataGrid.DataSource = tabela;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Sei que esta errado, mas nunca fiz esse tipo de coisa, então se puderem me ajudar, seria muito bom!

## EDIT

Estou conseguindo varrer o XML, mas só até uma certa tag... Como posso pegar tudo ? Só consigo varrer até a tag 13.

Códigos:

```
 if (openFileDialogXML.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialogXML.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        //limpa o conteudo do textbox
                        txtCaminhoArquivoXML.Text = "";

                        // Le os arquivos selecionados 
                        foreach (String arquivo in openFileDialogXML.FileNames)
                        {
                            txtCaminhoArquivoXML.Text += arquivo;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            // carrega e exibe o arquivo XML(le o conteudo do xml que esta no caminho do diretório)
                            StreamReader SR = File.OpenText(txtCaminhoArquivoXML.Text);
                            string _stringXml = SR.ReadToEnd();
                            SR.Close();

                            _stringXml = _stringXml.Replace("\n", "");
                            _stringXml = _stringXml.Replace("\r", "");

                            //faz o parse de uma string para uma representação de XML
                            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_stringXml);

                            //cria a representação de uma tabela
                            DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag1", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag2", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag3", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag4", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag5", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag6", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag7", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag8", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag9", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag10", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag11", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag12", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag13", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag14", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag15", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag16", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag17", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag18", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag19", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag20", typeof(string));

                            //cria as linhas da tabela
                            DataRow registro;

                            //itera sobre a tag do xml para pegar todos os dados 
                            foreach (var elmCertidao in doc.Root.Elements("emissao"))
                            {
                                //recebe os registros do xml e representa em linhas
                                registro = tabela.NewRow();

                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmCertidao.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));

                                //objeto com todas as colunas
                                tabela.Rows.Add(registro);
                            }

                            //monta o grid com as informações presentes no objeto
                            dgDataGrid.DataSource = tabela;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao carregar arquivo : " + ex.Message);
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Não foi possível ler o arquivo a partir do disco. Erro original: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dá algum tipo de erro? Se sim, qual? Se der um DataBind() no Grid, ele mostra alguma coisa?

Comment: Simplesmente não monta o grid. Não consigo carregar o conteudo do xml na variavel `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(docLoaded);`.

Comment: Já tentou inspecionar `doc`? O que aparece nas propriedades?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, no seu código não tem nenhum Bind no grid. Você deveria dar dgDataGrid.DataBind(), após a linha onde você define o DataSource do mesmo.

Comment: Então, agora eu consigo carregar os dados do xml, mas não aparece todos os dados que tem nele. Sò aparece o dado que está no primeiro no, e não nos outros. =(. Posso colocar meu código atualizado ? E ver se vocês me ajudam ?

Comment: @pnet e Cigano, consegui resolver! Obrigado pela atenção. Até respondi já minha pergunta pra ajudar outras pessoas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver de forma bem simples. Note que no código, tenho *foreach's* que iteram sobre todas as *tags* do *XML* para pegar o valor existente nelas.

Còdigos:

```
private void tsbImportarXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Configura a janela que abre para o usuário escolher o arquivo
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialogXML = new OpenFileDialog();

        //Já abre a janela dentro do C:
        openFileDialogXML.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";

        //Tipos de arquivo
        openFileDialogXML.Filter = "Arquivos XML (*.XML)|*.XML|Todos os Arquivos (*.*)|*.*";

        //Obtém ou define o índice do filtro selecionado atualmente na caixa de diálogo de arquivo. 
        openFileDialogXML.FilterIndex = 2;

        //Obtém ou define um valor indicando se a caixa de diálogo restaura o diretório atual antes de fechar. 
        openFileDialogXML.RestoreDirectory = true;

        #region Carregamento do XML no Grid

        if (openFileDialogXML.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialogXML.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        //limpa o conteudo do textbox
                        txtCaminhoArquivoXML.Text = "";

                        // Le os arquivos selecionados 
                        foreach (String arquivo in openFileDialogXML.FileNames)
                        {
                            txtCaminhoArquivoXML.Text += arquivo;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            // carrega e exibe o arquivo XML(le o conteudo do xml que esta no caminho do diretório)
                            StreamReader SR = File.OpenText(txtCaminhoArquivoXML.Text);
                            string _stringXml = SR.ReadToEnd();
                            SR.Close();

                            _stringXml = _stringXml.Replace("\n", "");
                            _stringXml = _stringXml.Replace("\r", "");

                            //faz o parse de uma string para uma representação de XML
                            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_stringXml);                            

                            //cria a representação de uma tabela
                            DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
                            tabela.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));

                            //cria as linhas da tabela
                            DataRow registro;

                            //itera sobre a tag do xml para pegar todos os dados 
                            foreach (var elmXML in doc.Root.Elements("tag"))
                            {
                                //recebe os registros do xml e representa em linhas
                                registro = tabela.NewRow();

                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(doc.Root.Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));

                                //itera sobre o subelemento gemeos dentro da tag root ali de cima
                                foreach (var elmXMLTag in elmXML.Elements("tag"))
                                {
                                    registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXMLTag.Element("tag"));

                                    //itera sobre o subelemento irmao dentro da tag ali de cima
                                    foreach (var elmXML2Tag in elmXMLTag.Elements("tag"))
                                    {
                                        registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML2Tag.Element("tag"));
                                    }                                       
                                }

                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));
                                registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmXML .Element("tag"));

                                foreach (var elmRej in doc.Root.Elements("tag"))
                                {
                                    registro["tag"] = GetValueOrDefault(elmRej.Element("tag"));
                                }


                                //objeto com todas as colunas
                                tabela.Rows.Add(registro);
                            }

                            //monta o grid com as informações presentes no objeto
                            dgDataGrid.DataSource = tabela;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao carregar arquivo : " + ex.Message);
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Não foi possível ler o arquivo a partir do disco. Erro original: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #region Métodos

    //verifica o primeiro valor e se for diferente de null retorna todas as informações do xml
    public static string GetValueOrDefault(XElement xElement)
    {
        if (xElement != null)
            return xElement.Value;

        return String.Empty;
    }

    #endregion
```

*tag leia-se o elemento do xml, o nó, a tag do xml.*
*txtCaminhoArquivoXML leia-se um campo de texto no form*